# java pie chart height is not properly placed

Tags: java, swing, charts, jfreechart, pie-chart

I am using JFreeChart to make a chart in my program. My problem is I cannot set the height properly. I have tried every command I could think of, I have put it in other panels, however, nothing works.
I want to be able to put it somewhere in a corner...or anywhere really and to be able to set both width and height. I have also tried with setPrefferedSize, but it only works with width.

Code :

```
DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
    result.setValue("TotalSwag", totalSwag);
    result.setValue("TotalYolo", totalYolo);
    result.setValue("TotalCool", totalCool);
    result.setValue("TotalLame", totalLame);
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("Swag-O-meter", result, true, true, false);
    PiePlot3D plot = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setStartAngle(290);
    plot.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);
    plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, W, H, W, H, W, H,
            false, true, true, true, true, true);
    chartPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 150));

    charPanel.add(chartPanel);
    charPanel.setSize(W, H);
    contentPane.add(charPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Comment: Try calling `frame.pack();` just before `frame.setVisible(true);`.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without forcing the size of the frame to be with what stuff it has inside? I'd like all windows to be the same size

Comment: Well my answer is the one that fixed it, but I can only accept it in 24 hours for some reason. Still, your addition was extremely useful, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to fix it, all I had to do is not use a flowLayout, but a grouplayout, since the panel was making the chart be enlarged, just like if you'd put a button in a flowLayout it would become the size of it's containing zone. Thank you everyone for the amazing help.

Comment: `FlowLayout` adopts the preferred size of the component. More on `GroupLayout` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8504753/230513). Are you using a GUI editor?

Comment: I am using it to set the layouts automatically, since I'm new at swing and I'm still a bit intimidated by some of the abilities it has. Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. Don't be afraid to experiment with [short, complete examples](http://sscce.org/), such as this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513), that may help you use the  editor while you learn.

Answer (score 3):

A `JFreeChart` is not a `JComponent`, but a `ChartPanel` is. You can control the size using any appropriate approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513).

> *I'd like all windows to be the same size*.

In this case, I'd override `getPreferredSize()` to return a `Dimension` having equal `width` and `height`. You can use `PiePlot#setCircular()` to preserve the aspect ratio of the `PiePlot`.

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7602126/230513) shows a `GridLayout(1, 0)` of charts each having a `ThermometerPlot`:

[image]

Comment: I managed to make the chart small in the corner, but there is still a huge gray area where the height was earlier.

Comment: I make the frame any size it's still there, usually it would be ok but it's covering a background image I loaded

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your approach. [`FauxImage`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8090328/230513) may be a convenient adjunct.

Comment: edited, also please don't judge on the values, it's a mini "ironic" project, which became terribly hard because of the pie chart